# Is there a way I can make this more elegant? I cant figure out any other way to write this

Tags: python, list, performance, loops, optimization

```
comboList = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
#duplicate values wont be entered into these test lists to begin with so idc about that
testList1 = [0,1,2]
testList2 = [1,2,4,7] 
testList3 = [0,2,3,6,5,69,4,6,1]
testList4 = [2,1,3] #this needs to return false

def testfunc(mainList, sublist):#This is the trash func
    for list in mainList: 
        y1 = 0
        x1 = 0
        while x1 < len(sublist):
            if sublist[x1] in list:
                y1 = y1 + 1
                if y1 == 3:
                    return True
            x1 = x1 + 1
    return False

if testfunc(comboList,testList1):
    print("Test1 Pass")
else:
    print("Test1 Fail")

if testfunc(comboList,testList2):
    print("Test2 Pass")
else:
    print("Test2 Fail")

if testfunc(comboList,testList3):
    print("Test3 Pass")
else:
    print("Test3 Fail")

if testfunc(comboList,testList4):
    print("Test4 Fail")
else:
    print("Test4 Pass")
```

I am fairly new to to this and I would like some feedback on how to write this more elegantly, this function is currently doing exactly what I want it to do but there should be a better way of doing it especially in python.

Comment: `list` - key word, you should never use it as a variable name

Comment: what are you expecting this function to do?

Comment: `list` is not a keyword. It's an ordinary identifier predefined in the built-in scope, but there is no harm (contrary to common belief) in reusing the name if you don't intend on using the original value in a particular scope.

Comment: yeah, I'm wrong, it's not keyword of course, it's built-in list class name, but there is no need to use it

Comment: `testfunc(comboList, [0,0,0])` is `True` - is that the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break down the logic into separate functions which are shorter and more readable, like this:

```
def has_n_items(iterable, n):
    """ Check whether an iterable has at least n items """
    for i, _ in enumerate(iterable, 1):
        if i == n:
            return True
    return False

def has_three_members(a, b):
    """ Test whether at least three members of b are found in a """
    return has_n_items((item for item in b if item in a), 3)
            
def test_func(a, b):
    """ Test whether at least three members of list b are found in any of the sublists of list of lists a """
    return any(has_three_members(b, items) for sublist in a)
```

Answer (score -1):

for improving your function you can do this:

```
def testfunc(mainList,sublist): 
    for l in mainList: 
        if sum(x in l for x in sublist) == len(l):
            return True
    return False
```

it pass the tests but idk if that's exactly what you want to do:

check for every val in `sublist` if match with values in one list of `mainList`. But checking your code and mine (do the same). it will return `True` if for example you use as `sublist= [0,0,0]`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm aware that some duplicate values will mess everything up but the data I'm working with will never have any so I'm fine with that.

Answer (score -2):

Any time you are testing membership amongst groups, you should be thinking of using `sets`.  If you have control over the original inputs, you should construct them as sets.  If you "receive" lists, you can convert them on the fly.  This will be galactically faster for "large" data.  For tiny examples such as yours, the speedup will not be noticed.

```
def member_test(main, test_list):
    return any(len(set(sub) & set(test_list)) >= 3 for sub in main)
```

This uses the `any` construct and set intersection to do the heavy lifting and forgoes the looping with a compact representation.